# Git server hook not work, including pre-receive/post-receive

Tags: git

Help:

1. I setup a git repo in my server with "git init --bare myproject",
2. I tried to enable hook in server side, and added a pre-receive script in hooks, the script content in pic

   [image: pre-receive bash]
3. When I did a push in client side, result is ok, the pre-receive looks like not trigger.

Anybody konw the root cause? miss configure?

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Please, do not post screenshots. Instead copy and format contents of script here so it is acessible to everyone.

Comment: @blami, I don't know how to list my image directly，this is the first time I use stackoverflow:-)

Comment: Here is awesome explanation https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/497127

Comment: @ShaZha Can we see the text output of `ls -lAF myproject/hooks/` at the server?

Comment: @phd, yes, all the hook script could list out.

Comment: I have tried in the other server, pre-receive hook work well, so  I think this issue may related with env...

Comment: @ShaZha Is it called exactly `pre-receive`? Is it executable? That what I tried to find out with `ls -l`